# what this gray chewy filler called?

Tags: repair, wood

can anyone tell me what this product is?

there is a grey chewy filler with paper inside used to fill bigger gaps on my staircase.  the smaller gaps are filled with caulk.

[image: stairs tread under carpet]

Comment: Upvote for chewy!  I might sometimes sniff some unknown stuff but so far no chewing.   I admire your deep analysis.

Comment: It looks to me like grey silicone sealant. I've never tried chewing it but I guess silicone sealant would be quite chewy..

Comment: If it is silicone, comes in a tube like this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Everbuild-450CL-Builders-Silicone-Sealant450/dp/B001GU6CNM

Comment: When this silicon cures, it becomes paper inside and that  gray rubber thing on the outside?  The paper is quite intriguing as I see it in crevices and I doubt anyone took the pain to push in there.

Comment: Could it be self-leveling compound?

Comment: There are many commercial sealants/caulkings that could have been used and the paper may just be filler.

Comment: the paper is not a filler that is why i am very curious in knowing more about this product. if the paper is a filler then i would be curious how they got it inside a space thru a tiny gap.